# Rails 5.2 encrypted credentials not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.2

When I do `bin/rails credentials:edit` my editor opens a file like `credentials.yml.enc.1234` with default content. After I'm done editing, I hit save, and the console reads `New credentials encrypted and saved.`

After I run `bin/rails credentials:edit` again, another temp file gets opened (`credentials.yml.enc.4321`) and the contents are back to default.

How can I make the credentials persist?

Comment: Do you set editor?

Comment: yes. Not helping so far.

Comment: the problem is that it saves the changes OK, I can see them with rails credentials:show, but when re-opening the file - everything is gone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue related to this:
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31286

It's been fixed already in 5.2.0.rc1

Answer (score 28):

If you aren't using `vim`, you need to add a `wait` flag to the editor.

e.g for `atom`:

```
EDITOR="atom --wait" rails credentials:edit
```

I ran into the same thing and found the answer [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28396#issuecomment-286016580).

Comment: I needed `EDITOR="subl --wait" rails credentials:edit` but otherwise, thanks!

Comment: Tried EDITOR="code --wait" rails credentials:edit since I use VSC - works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I also had this problem with using atom as editor. 
I have tried:

```
EDITOR="atom --wait" rails credentials:edit
```

and

```
EDITOR="atom -w" rails credentials:edit
```

but no results. Finally, I used nano (ubuntu):

```
EDITOR="nano" rails credentials:edit
```

For me, this works fine. Maybe, it will be helpful for someone, as an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem in rails 5.2.0 using textmate as the editor. It turns out the credentials file must be closed after save in order for the changes to persist.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following for opening the credentials file in sublime.

```
EDITOR="subl --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit
```

Make sure you close the credentials file in sublime after making the changes.
Also restart your server to view the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled a bit with this one due to the fact that I was not capitalizing EDITOR. The commmand

```
editor="vim" rails credentials:edit
```

directly saves the credentials without opportunity to edit. The guidance tells you to add the --wait flag. To me, it was not about the --wait flag but about the capitalization. This was working:

```
EDITOR="vim" rails credentials:edit
```

(no --wait flat but capitalized EDITOR)

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble myself, eventually got it all working with TextEdit on OS X.

`EDITOR="open -a TextEdit --wait" rails credentials:edit`

That opens the editing but after saving and closing the file, I still didn't get the changes persisted. I needed to also quit TextEdit.

So if you want to use TextEdit to edit credentials on OS X Ventura you can do it with the above command, then save the file, then quit TextEdit.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with Rails 7.0.1.

First I opened the encrypted YAML:

```
EDITOR='code --wait' rails credentials:edit
```

Inside the encrypted YAML I added the needed credential:

```
devise_jwt_secret_key:
XXXXXXXXXX
```

Then in VSCode I saved the YAML file and exited out of the file tab (top right of the tab):

Terminal output:

```
File encrypted and saved.
```