# Using dotenv in production, or passing env variables to js/js.erb? and attempt with credentials

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I am attempting to pass my ENV variable of my stripe publishable key to the stripe.js file for Connect.

**Dotenv gem:**

```
gem 'dotenv-rails', groups: [:development, :test, :production]
```

I added it to my dotenv gem .env file:

```
STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY=pk_test_xxxxxxxxxx
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY=sk_test_xxxxxxxxxx
```

Then added to my stripe.js.erb file:

```
var stripe = Stripe("<%= ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY']%>");
```

changing the stripe.js to stripe.js.erb worked locally, but the ENV doesn't seem to work in production.  Within Heroku variables, I have it set.  And if I pass the key directly in the stripe.js/.js/erb it will work, so one way or another, the ENV isn't working during production.

Even if i take the code into the views with  tags, it won't work unless i pass the key directly in.

I receive no errors on herokus side.

**I also tried using credentials:**

```
stripe:
  stripe_publishable_key: pk_test_x
  stripe_secret_key: sk_test_x
```

With this in my stripe.js/.js.erb file:

```
  var stripe = Stripe('<%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:stripe, :stripe_publishable_key) %>');
```

(i use this exact format for active storage and works
and tried:

```
 var stripe = Stripe('<%= Rails.application.credentials.stripe[:stripe_publishable_key] %>');
```

With these i get the following error pushing to heroku   :

> NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

**Questions:** How can I pass the ENV variables through to production?

That question was solved by using .erb, but now the problem is the ENV file not reaching production.

Comment: Aside from the .env dotenv issue.... apparently credentials has an issue with Atom, which is what i use??? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48539408/rails-5-2-encrypted-credentials-not-saving

Comment: How exactly do you know it's not working in production? Have you checked the rendered JS? Also, this is pretty much of a duplicate of your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55370201/using-dotenv-env-for-stripe-error-invalid-api-key-provided ... it's best not to make multiple questions for the same issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Dotenv env for stripe "Error: Invalid API Key provided: <%=\*\*\*\['\*\*\*\*\*\*\_\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\_\*\*\*'\]%>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55370201/using-dotenv-env-for-stripe-error-invalid-api-key-provided)

Comment: @maxpleaner Because the ENV doesn't pass through in production.  The stripe credit card entry doesn't appear with it... in local it does.  but in production is i use the key directly in the code it works.  It's not that the JS isn't being rendered, its that the ENV isn't being passed into the production -- this is my assumption.

Comment: Did you commit and push your `.env` file?

Answer (score 0):

If you have remembered to precompile your assets (which I often forget when dealing with heroku), you will need to add the js.erb file to the precompile list explicitly ([SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275846/rails-wont-precompile-js-erb), [more detailed blog post](https://launchschool.com/blog/rails-asset-pipeline-best-practices))

In this case though, you actually do not need to wrap this up in a variable anyway. The publishable key can be (should be) included to identify your Stripe account and the interpolation is going to send it in plain text anyway (what you normally want to avoid by using ENV variables) so you can skip the interp step entirely.

**Edit from comments:**
You need to verify that the env key is actually set on Heroku. There are two ways to check:

- login to the CLI and check
- check also through the settings in the dashboard ([this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) has examples on how to do both)

If you're getting an empty string in the compiled JS then that would at least indicate that the ERB is getting processed so the error is likely that there is nothing to interpolate when it is.

Just to reiterate there's no reason to hide a the publishable key (that's why it's called that and why the docs pass it in the clear). Furthermore putting it in an ENV that gets interpolated into text isn't hiding anything anyway.

Comment: Already have `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << '*.js'
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << '*.js.erb'` in my assets.

Comment: When you look at the JS file being delivered, is it interpolated correctly?

Comment: I'm confused.  So I am using Stripe Elements and in the stripe.js: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart i need to pass the publishable key in the js file.  Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I literally have no idea what that means.  But when i check in Sources, the JS file is rendering and passing through.  My assumption is that if the ENV or crednetials passed the key through, it would work..... idk

Comment: When you look in sources you see a variable that looks exactly like this (with a different key ofc): `var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_x5T4dHozsoJKgbvSZewKa07');`?

Comment: That happens only if i pass the key directly into the .js or js.erb file.  When i use the ENV[: or credentials, I get nothing.

Comment: Thats actually why i started doing this because i saw the test key was in the sources, which i assume wouldn't be safe so i wanted to somehow hide that but still have everything work out

Comment: Updated based on comments. At least it sounds like your erb is getting processed so it's likely just that the ENV is not set

Comment: Okay, ended up being because i had "PUBLISHABLE KEY" in heroku set, but had "STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY" set in .env and credentials.... wow,4 hours later.  But now my concern is that even with that, I can still see the test publishable key in the sources. If i can see it, can't everyone else? If i go to live, will it go away, I don't understand now

Comment: and btw thanks for helping.  very much so appreciated a lot

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. If I were you I would go ahead and swap everything over to credentials now that it is working. It's more secure and it won't require you to upload your .env file to source control (which defeats the whole point of env variables anyway). Also see edit: there is nothing wrong with sending the user a publishable key, it is required to identify the app

Comment: Well, the publishable key is on heroku, are you saying to remove that from heroku and just use credentials instead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190755/discussion-between-oneworkingheadphone-and-uno).

Comment: My concern is people getting a hold of the live publishable key, isn't that a security concern?..

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgotten to set `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` environment variable in your Heroku app while using credentials approach. From your codebase assign content of `master.key` to it.